# Inserting data (bar charts and weather info) into SVG Circles

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to create a visual effect (using D3.js and json) where 4 small circles will pop up once I click on the big yellow circle. I want to make sure that ***ALL of the circles*** will present pieces of information that I'm trying to assign to each and every one of them. I plan to have:
  -The 1st big yellow circle to present the weather (sunny, mostly cloudy, etc)
  -2 small circles to present weather info by word
  -2 small circles present a D3 bar chart that I made, along with some    weather info by word
   (I have all of the info separated by spaces and comments)

However, my problem is (for the lack of a better explanation) that I am just stumped! I have no idea how to make that happen. I would really appreciate it if I can get help from you guys. Here's my code (HTML and JS):
     
      
      
      
        var h = 2000;
        var w = 2000;
        var xGrid = 300;
        var yGrid = 300;
        var radius = 300;

```
    var svg = d3.select("body")
         .append("svg")
         .attr("width", w)
         .attr("height", h);

    var shape = svg.append("circle")
         .attr("cx", xGrid)
         .attr("cy", yGrid)
         .attr("r", radius)
         .style("fill", "yellow");

         shape.on("click", function(){
       var circle1 = svg.append("circle")
           //.attr("cx", (xGrid-radius/2)+0)
           //.attr("cy", (yGrid-radius/2)+0)
          .attr("cx", xGrid - radius/2)
          .attr("cy", yGrid - radius/2)
           .attr("r", radius/2)
           .style("fill", "red");
       var circle2 = svg.append("circle")
           //.attr("cx", (xGrid-radius/2)+10)
           //.attr("cy", (yGrid-radius/2)+10)
          .attr("cx", xGrid + radius/2)
          .attr("cy", yGrid - radius/2)
           .attr("r", radius/2)
           .style("fill", "blue");
       var circle3 = svg.append("circle")
          // .attr("cx", (xGrid-radius/2)+20)
          // .attr("cy", (yGrid-radius/2)+20)
          .attr("cx", xGrid - radius/2)
          .attr("cy", yGrid + radius/2)
           .attr("r", radius/2)
           .style("fill", "green");
       var circle4 = svg.append("circle")
          // .attr("cx", (xGrid-radius/2)+30)
        //.attr("cy", (yGrid-radius/2)+30)
           .attr("cx", xGrid + radius/2)
           .attr("cy", yGrid + radius/2)
           .attr("r", radius/2)
           .style("fill", "purple");
   });
   <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// /////////////////
///////////////////////////////(END)  Circle Pop-up  (END)/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
  </script>

   <!--///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// ////////////////////////
///////////////////////////(START) Info for circles to present   (START)////////////////////////////////
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// //////////////////////////////-->

```
   <!--/////Main Circle display/////////-->
   <p id="w"></p><p id="main"></p>
   <!--//////Circle 1 (upper left corner) display///////////-->
   <p id="rh"></p><p id="c1a"></p>
   <!--///////Circle 2 (upper right corner) display//////////-->
   <p id="ws"></p><p id="c2a"></p>
   <p id="wd"></p><p id="c2b"></p>
   <p id="we"></p><p id="c2c"></p>
   <p id="wm"></p><p id="c2d"></p>

   <!--////////Circle 3 (lower left corner) display/////////-->
   <p id="pti"></p><p id="c3a"></p>
   <p id="ptc"></p><p id="c3b"></p>
   <p id="df"></p><p id="c3c"></p>
   <p id="dc"></p><p id="c3d"></p>
   <!--///////Circle 4 (lower right corner) display//////////-->
   <p id="hif"></p><p id="c4a"></p>
   <p id="hic"></p><p id="c4b"></p>
   <p id="sr"></p><p id="c4c"></p>
   <p id="uv"></p><p id="c4d"></p>

   <script type = "text/javascript">
    var dataForMainCircle = '{"weather": "Mostly Cloudy"}';
    var mcDis= JSON.parse(dataForMainCircle);
    var weather = "weather: ";
    document.getElementById("w").innerHTML = weather;
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = mcDis.weather;
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ////////////Setup for display of 1st circle info///////////////////////////////////
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     var dataForCircle1b = '{"relative_humidity": "92%"}';
     var relativeHum = "Relative Humidity: ";
      var c1Dis = JSON.parse(dataForCircle1b);
     d3.json("js/tempGraph.json", function (data) {
          var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                      .attr("width", 500)
                      .attr("height", 500)
              canvas.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                           .append("rect")
                           .attr("width", function (d) {return d.temp * 10; })
                           .attr("height", 48)
                           .attr("y", function (d,i) {return i * 50; })
                           .attr("fill", "red");
               canvas.selectAll("text")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                           .append("text")
                           .attr("fill", "white")
                           .attr("y", function (d,i) {return i * 50 + 24;   })
                           .text(function (d) {return d.temp; })
     })
     document.getElementById("rh").innerHTML = relativeHum;
     document.getElementById("c1a").innerHTML = c1Dis.relative_humidity;
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  / ////////////////////Setup for display of 2nd circle info////////////////////////////////////
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var dataForCircle2 = '{"wind_string": "Calm", "wind_dir": "SW",   "wind_degrees": 229, "wind_mph": 2}';
    var c2Dis = JSON.parse(dataForCircle2);
    var windCon = "Wind Condition: ";
    var windDir = "Wind Direction: ";
    var windDeg = "Wind Degree: ";
    var windMph = "Wind (Miles Per Hour): "
    document.getElementById("ws").innerHTML = windCon;
    document.getElementById("c2a").innerHTML = c2Dis.wind_string;

    document.getElementById("wd").innerHTML = windDir;
    document.getElementById("c2b").innerHTML = c2Dis.wind_dir;

    document.getElementById("we").innerHTML = windDeg;
    document.getElementById("c2c").innerHTML = c2Dis.wind_degrees;

    document.getElementById("wm").innerHTML = windMph;
    document.getElementById("c2d").innerHTML = c2Dis.wind_mph;

   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// //////////////////////////////////
     //Setup for display of 3rd circle  info/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// ////////////////////////////////
   var dataForCircle3 = '{"precip_today_in": "0.00",    "precip_today_metric": "0"}';
   var c3Dis = JSON.parse(dataForCircle3);
   var predate = "Today's Precipitation: ";
   var prem = "Precipitation Metric: ";
   //var dewF = "Dewpoint-F: ";
   //var dewC = "Dewpoint-C: ";
   document.getElementById("pti").innerHTML = predate;
   document.getElementById("c3a").innerHTML = c3Dis.precip_today_in;

    document.getElementById("ptc").innerHTML = prem;
    document.getElementById("c3b").innerHTML = c3Dis.precip_today_metric;

    //document.getElementById("df").innerHTML = dewF;
    //document.getElementById("c3c").innerHTML = c3Dis.dewpoint_f;
    d3.json("js/dewGraph.json", function (data) {
       var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                     .attr("width", 500)
                     .attr("height", 500)
              canvas.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                           .append("rect")
                           .attr("width", function (d) {return d.dewpoint  * 10; })
                           .attr("height", 48)
                           .attr("y", function (d,i) {return i * 50; })
                           .attr("fill", "white");
              canvas.selectAll("text")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                           .append("text")
                           .attr("fill", "white")
                           .attr("y", function (d,i) {return i * 50 + 24;   })
                           .text(function (d) {return d.dewpoint; })
     })
      //document.getElementById("dc").innerHTML = dewC;
      //document.getElementById("c3d").innerHTML = c3Dis.dewpoint_c;
  <!--//////////////Setup for display of 4th circle    display////////////////////-->
    var dataForCircle4 = '{"heat_index_f": "NA", "heat_index_c": "NA", "solarradiation": "--", "UV": "0"}';
   var c4Dis = JSON.parse(dataForCircle4);
   var heatF = "Heat Index-F: ";
   var heatC = "Heat Index-C: ";
   var sunR = "Solar Radiation: ";
   var ultraV = "UV: ";
    document.getElementById("hif").innerHTML = heatF;
    document.getElementById("c4a").innerHTML = c4Dis.heat_index_f;

     document.getElementById("hic").innerHTML = heatC;
     document.getElementById("c4b").innerHTML = c4Dis.heat_index_c;

      document.getElementById("sr").innerHTML = sunR;
      document.getElementById("c4c").innerHTML = c4Dis.solarradiation;

      document.getElementById("uv").innerHTML = ultraV;
      document.getElementById("c4d").innerHTML = c4Dis.UV;

        d3.json("js/tempGraph.json", function (data) {
            var canvas1 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                           .attr("width", 500)
                           .attr("height", 500)
              canvas1.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                           .append("rect")
                           .attr("width", function (d) {return d.temp *     10; })
                           .attr("height", 48)
                           .attr("y", function (d,i) {return i * 50; })
                           .attr("fill", "red");
                canvas1.selectAll("text")
                         .data(data)
                         .enter()
                           .append("text")
                           .attr("fill", "white")
                           .attr("y", function (d,i) {return i * 50 + 24;    })
                           .text(function (d) {return d.temp; })
      })
          d3.json("js/dewGraph.json", function (data) {
             var canvas2 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                      .attr("width", 500)
                      .attr("height", 500)
               canvas2.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                           .append("rect")
                           .attr("width", function (d) {return d.dewpoint    * 10; })
                           .attr("height", 48)
                           .attr("y", function (d,i) {return i * 50; })
                           .attr("fill", "blue");
               canvas2.selectAll("text")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                           .append("text")
                           .attr("fill", "white")
                           .attr("y", function (d,i) {return i * 50 + 24;         })
                           .text(function (d) {return d.dewpoint; })
   })
   </script>        
   </body>
   </html>
```

Keep in mind, this program is sort of a prototype. My main concern is getting the info assigned for the circles INSIDE of them. If you guys found any errors/mix-ups in the code, feel free to notify me. Thank you!!

Comment: Hi! I have taken a couple of minutes to go through your code. I must say: i don't really fully understand the intent. Could you perhaps attach a simple drawing/image of what it is you would want? Perhaps I can just create a simple example with some explanation.

Comment: I do see some misunderstandings in your code as well. At the start of your code, you append an svg and in that svg you put circles, which will overlap a bit. Then for every .json file you read, you append a new svg. Those svg's will be placed under each other. I think you want the dewgraph and the tempgraph information inside the circles, but with the current code, you place separate svg's containing the info under each other. This makes me believe you don't fully understand D3 basics yet, which is why i would go for a simple example :-)

Comment: Oh and [this](http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2013/03/05/d3-tutorial-at-strata-redux/) might be very helpful to  you as well!

Comment: You are right; I am trying to put info inside the circles. I admit, I'm just too eager to on completing on the project, I've spent little time on the D3 basics. Would you mind providing the example. By the way, here's the visual aid that you wanted to see.

Comment: i ll look into an example asap :-). Dont see the visual aid though...

Comment: It says that I need 10 reps in order to post images :/  I'm kind of new here. Basically, im just trying to put stuff in circles. Thanks again for looking

Comment: np :-) i can do that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as promised, an example. It doesn't look super cool, but at least you will get the picture. If you have more questions, please shoot! Here goes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="donut.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color:black;
        }
        #container {
            position:relative;
            display:inline-block;
            width:100%;
        }
        .row{
            position:relative;
            display:inline-block;
            width:100%;
            text-align:center;
        }
        #chart{
            width:60%;
            position:relative;
            display:inline-block;
        }
        text{
            font-size:1.4em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="chart">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var data = [
            {"type":"weather", "status":"sunny"},
            {"type":"humidity", "status":"high"},
            {"type":"temperature", "status":"23°"},
            {"type":"pressure", "status":"1040 hpa"},
            {"type":"wind", "status":"East"},
        ];

        var chartWidth = 500;
        var chartHeight = 500;

        /* Adding the svg drawing canvas by selecting the element that will contain the svg. put it in a var,
            as it is a d3 selection. We can reuse this selection. Remember, when chaining, you will get returned the
            element you last appended, in this case the svg.
        */
        var svg = d3.select("#chart")
                        .append("svg")
                            .attr({   // you can put attributes in a javascript object, i like this notation better.
                                width:chartWidth,
                                height:chartHeight
                            });


        /*  Here I am going to add the circles. With SVG elements, you cannot draw inside other elements. There are only 2 elements
            which can contain other elements (as far as I know) and that is the SVG element itself and the g element. So if you want 
            to give the impression that the elements are inside one another, you need to make them overlap. So if I add a circle and then
            add text with coordinates that match the circle, the text will overlap the circle, giving the impression it is inside it.
        */

        var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
                            .data(data) //binding the data. I want 5 circles for my 5 pieces of data
                            .enter()
                            .append("circle")
                                .attr({
                                    cx:function(d,i){ //when doing the append on a d3 selection, you are iteration over each element!
                                        /* I will use the index (i) to 'identify' the pieces of data and to hardcode their x central point positions */

                                        if(i == 0) {
                                            return chartWidth/2;
                                        }

                                        if(i == 1) {
                                            return chartWidth/5;
                                        }

                                        if(i == 2) {
                                            return chartWidth *(2/7);
                                        }

                                        if(i == 3) {
                                            return chartWidth *(5/7);
                                        }

                                        if(i == 4) {
                                            return chartWidth * (4/5);
                                        }
                                    },
                                    cy:function(d,i){ //when doing the append on a d3 selection, you are iteration over each element!
                                        /* I will use the index (i) to 'identify' the pieces of data and to hardcode their y central point positions */

                                        if(i == 0) {
                                            return chartHeight/2;
                                        }

                                        if(i == 1) {
                                            return chartHeight *(3/5);
                                        }

                                        if(i == 2) {
                                            return chartHeight *(4/5);
                                        }

                                        if(i == 3) {
                                            return chartHeight *(4/5);
                                        }

                                        if(i == 4) {
                                            return chartHeight * (3/5);
                                        }
                                    },
                                    r:function(d,i) { /* the radius is in function of the type. The first one (weather) should be the biggest one */
                                        if(d.type === "weather") {
                                            return 200;
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            return 75;
                                        }
                                    },
                                    fill:"yellow",
                                    stroke:"black"
                                });

            /* Now i'll append the text as last, so it overlaps nicely with the circles. For positioning, i ll have to reuse the x and y functions
                from the circles. I want the text to be positioned at the center of the cirkels.
            */          
            var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
                                    .data(data)
                                    .enter()
                                    .append("text")
                                        .text(function(d){ return d.status})
                                        .attr({
                                            x:function(d,i){ 
                                                /* So I used the same positioning for the text as for the center points of the circles.
                                                    you should realize that the text really starts at the middle of the circles. So you
                                                    should substract a bit from the x position to get them nicely in the middle. I aint going
                                                    for that trouble, its just an example.
                                                */

                                                if(i == 0) {
                                                    return chartWidth/2;
                                                }

                                                if(i == 1) {
                                                    return chartWidth/5;
                                                }

                                                if(i == 2) {
                                                    return chartWidth *(2/7);
                                                }

                                                if(i == 3) {
                                                    return chartWidth *(5/7);
                                                }

                                                if(i == 4) {
                                                    return chartWidth * (4/5);
                                                }
                                            },
                                            y:function(d,i){ //when doing the append on a d3 selection, you are iteration over each element!
                                                /* I will use the index (i) to 'identify' the pieces of data and to hardcode their y central point positions */

                                                if(i == 0) {
                                                    return chartHeight/2;
                                                }

                                                if(i == 1) {
                                                    return chartHeight *(3/5);
                                                }

                                                if(i == 2) {
                                                    return chartHeight *(4/5);
                                                }

                                                if(i == 3) {
                                                    return chartHeight *(4/5);
                                                }

                                                if(i == 4) {
                                                    return chartHeight * (3/5);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I did not add the function to click on the first circle to show the others. I could if you want me to though, but I felt like this example already has enough stuff in it to learn from.

Comment: For now, I just have 1 question. It's more of a theory: You mentioned that I could have text overlap the svg element w/ precise coordinates in your comments.. Would it be possible if I could use that same method to make my bar graph overlap the element(circle)?

Comment: Well, i am not a D3 expert, but if I would have to do that, I would do it like this as well. But... I would put my barchart in a g element however. And then adjust the position of teh g element